# How to reuse examples in unit tests?

Tags: r, unit-testing, documentation, roxygen2, testthat

Let's say I have a function, documented with an example (using roxygen):

```
#' @title Add two numbers
#' @param x a scalar
#' @param y a scalar
#' @examples 
#' testobj <- add(x + y)

add <- function(x, y) {
  return(x+y)
}
```

Now I *also* want to run some tests on the resulting object, to make sure the function does as it should.
I'll use `testthat` for that:

```
context("Adding stuff")

testobj <- add(x, y) # THIS is the duplicate line that bothers me.

test_that(desc = "Additions work", code = {
  testthat::expect_length(object = x, n = 1)
})
```

How can I **reuse the `testobj` created in the example** and then run some tests on it in `testthat`?

It's trivial in this case, but it leads to substantial duplication if the function is more complex.

Or am I using this wrong?

Comment: I've now added an [issue for testthat](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/1308) to consider adding a more idiomatic way to share code/objects between tests, examples, vignettes and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `example` function exported from `utils` to run the examples contained in the documentation of a function.

```
testobj <- example(add)
# add> testobj <- add(x, y)
```

Note that it is recommended to use concrete examples in your roxygen comments:

Instead of

```
#' @examples 
#' testobj <- add(x, y)
```

Use

```
#' @examples 
#' testobj <- add(2, 3)
```